# html look up field

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications

How to create an html look up field. So, I want to achieve

1. an html input field, with an icon/button next to it
2. when user click on it, a pop-up window displays with a search form (I assume this can be created beforehand and hide using javascript)
3. user apply search, and data is displayed in the same (pop-up) window
4. when user select a value and apply ok, the field value is copied to the original input filed, and pop-up window closes.

Any sample code? Is there any simple way without using any java script library? or any simple plugin for jquery.

thanks.

Comment: There is no way to do it without javascript or server-side language.

Comment: I am developing a web app, so some details from the server.. say, customer, supplier etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be possible, but very unwise to do this without any libraries or plug-ins.

I strongly recommend [jQuery UI's Dialog widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).  It's very simple, well documented and easy to use.

You will probably be interested specifically in [how to use the Dialog to display a form](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form).  Click the View Source link on that page to see all of the mark-up and code required to achieve that effect.